# Are all Pixar movies set in the same universe?

Tags: pixar

I heard someone say that all the Pixar movies are set in the same universe. Is this true?

A casual web search led me to [this](http://www.pixartheory.com/), but I'm not sure if it's canon or not.

Does anyone know any details about this?

Comment: Interesting link

Comment: I can't believe it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: [I didn't find another](http://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=pixar+same+universe)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson i remmebrr seeing this [before](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21212831#21212831) but can't trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Possibly, but it doesn’t seem to be by design.**

A Pixar employee, Jay Ward, who was fairly involved in *Cars*, was asked about this shortly after the posting of Negroni’s theory in an interview with Jason Torchinsky at io9. He rebuts the theory:

> **JT:** What do you think about it?
>
> **JW:** I think somebody had a lot of time on their hands. They may have had some other recreational activities…
>
> **JT:** So would you go as far as to deny that there's a common thread —
>
> **JW:** It's almost like the 9/11 conspiracy theories… it’s like, really? No, the movies were sort of made in a different order by different directors in different times, in different places. It's cool that it all worked out that way, but it probably was not intentional.
>
> — [*Pixar’s Jay Ward responds to the unified Pixar movie theory*](http://jalopnik.com/pixars-jay-ward-responds-to-the-unified-pixar-movie-th-822973346)

He’s the only Pixar employee I’ve ever seen discussing the theory, so unless another answerer can find somebody different, I’m inclined to say that it really is just a theory.

As a side note, Cracked and Negroni were by no means the first people to propose the idea of a shared universe (although Negroni might be the most detailed suggestion). There’s a Wikipedia article for [the Pixar Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixar_Theory), which says “Media discussion about a “Pixar Universe” has existed since at least 2003”.

*(This is copied from my answer to [Is there any official evidence for the Pixar theory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/65391/3567) on the Science-Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange.)*